# WPML custom string translation get outside of container

Tags: translation, plugin-wpml

I am trying to add a custom string to translate in wpml, but when I use the _e(...) the content jumps outside of container

if I use like this:

```
echo '<h1>' . $month . ' ' . $day . '</h1>';
```

the html is ok:

```
<h1>September 29</h1>
```

but if I use with translation like this:

```
echo '<h1>' . _e($month, 'simultan') . ' ' . $day . '</h1>';
```

the translated string jumps out of h1:

```
Septembrie<h1>29</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `_e` your echoing the translated string. But you already have an `echo` so just use `__(`.

This is the correct code for your example

```
echo '<h1>' . __('September', 'simultan') . ' ' . $day . '</h1>';
```

If you want to add variables in your translations you should use `sprintf` like this:

```
$date = sprintf ( __('%s %d', 'simultan'), $month, $day );
echo '<h1>' . $date . '</h1>';
```

You might want to also have a look at [date_i18n](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/) function since you are translating dates.

Reference:

[Wordpress I18N](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/)

[sprintf manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)